vs code how to remove three dots buttons and explorer title
I'm just wondering if I could delete those useless(for me) interface elements in vs code, since I'm used to ctrl + shift + p, I never use 3 dots buttons and hardly ever look at the project name.
vscode screenshot
I've tried right clicking at it, but I can't delete this way these elements.
Also I've checked settings, didn't find anything useful, maybe I'm missing something.

Maybe try writing custom color scheme, that would visually hide it?

@Justinas Actually good idea, but I'm not sure if color scheme could really hide it, not make it transparent. I've never tried writing custom color scheme

I doubt you can get rid of the more... buttons, but you can get rid of the window title with the setting: Window: Custom Title Bar Visibility.

if you are so low on screen real-estate buy a bigger monitor, 4K has enough room, you can use F11
